# Redis with Node js - module.exports issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, nodes

I am using Redis.lab cloud service.  I have setup my node.js app to access it. The connection seems fine and I can set data into it.  The problem is when I define the redis client in a service file and export the client object to another file to use it, it doesn't seem working.  If I create the redis client directly under that file it works just fine. Is there any limitation with the Redis.lab sevice?  I am more leaning toward I did something wrong.  Appreciate your suggestions.  Below is the code. (the 1st is the service file where the redis client is defined. it is located under /services folder)

```js
const { createClient } = require("redis");

// Initialize client
const redisClient = createClient({
  password: process.env.REDIS_SERVER_PASSWORD,
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_SERVER_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_SERVER_PORT,
  },
});

redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);
redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("Connected to redis successfully");
});

redisClient.set("message", "testmessage", function (err, reply) {
  console.log(reply); // OK
});

module.exports = redisClient;
```

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const session = require("express-session");
    const redisClient = require("./services/redis");
    const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;
// Initialize store.
const redisStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: "myapp:",
});

//Configure session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    store: redisStore,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
      httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5, // session max age in miliseconds
    },
  })
);
```

then the controller file (located under /controllers from project root directory) where I want to use the client to write some session data into it. I also try "redisClient.set("name", "Kim");" but it doesn't work either.  It doesn't write the data into the Redis at all.  If I create the client directly in this file, the set and hset work just fine.

```js
const redisClient = require("./../services/redis");
exports.MySession = async (req, res) => {
  try {
   
    await redisClient.hSet(req.sessionID, {
      name: "John",
      surname: "Smith",
      company: "Redis",
      age: 29,
    });

    res.send("working in progress...");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: When `const redisClient = require("./services/redis");` is used,  `console.log("Connected to redis successfully");` logs correctly?

Comment: I recommend listening to the error on the client `client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));`